# How do you tell if a word is in alphabetical order in python?

Tags: python

I really have no idea how to go about this. So far all I have is this:

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

I am supposed to go through a text file and count the number of words in alphabetical order.
I can't do

```
if word in alphabet:
```

because that requires the word to actually have all of those letters in order.

To clarify: 'blow' would pass the test and 'suck' would not.
I have a list of thousands of words, I need to go through the entire list and count the numbers of words that are in alphabetical order. Sorry for any prior confusion.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to test if a word has each of its letters in alphabetical order?  
So, to be clear, "blow" would pass this test, and "suck" would not.

Comment: is this homework? @JordaanMylonas I think he means for `alpha bravo whiskey charlie`. it would return `3` because 3 of the 4 words are in alphabetical order.

Comment: Feel free to remove the homework tag if this isn't homework, but that's what it looks like to me.

Comment: @JordaanMylonas Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very simple:

```
>>> alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>> list(alphabet) == sorted(alphabet)
True
>>> list('blow') == sorted('blow')
True
>>> list('suck') == sorted('suck')
False
```

So know we can define the predicate we need:

```
>>> alphabetical = lambda w: list(w.lower()) == sorted(w.lower())
```

And apply it to a list:

```
>>> lst = ['blow', 'suck', 'abc']
>>> filter(alphabetical, lst)
['blow', 'abc']
```

From there it's not a large step to counting the results :) There's some other things to consider:

- The sorting is `O(n*log n)`, although this problem could easily be solved in `O(n)`. This is probably okay because words usually have a bounded number of characters and `sorted` is implemented in C and thus very fast
- If you really need efficiency, you can even use the `sum(1 for w in w if ...)` trick, which uses a generator expression instead of building a list.

Comment: This was the method that occurred to me. It beats any other on simplicity, even though it is theoretically O(nlogn) rather than O(n). This may be disallowed because this is homework, though.

Comment: @agf: Well, there's nothing about `O(n)` in the question, so simplicity wins for me :)

Comment: why are you using a lambda instead of a def ?

Comment: @wim: Dunno, looks better IMHO. I usually prefer `lambda`s over functions in such simple cases.

Comment: Assigning a lambda to a name goes against the whole point of lambda keyword, which is for an anonymous function.  For simple cases, you can still put a `def` on one line if you like the way it looks as a one line.

Comment: @wim: I like the way it's obvious how this is just a name for a simple expression/predicate. With `def`, I have to add parantheses and a return. Coming from a functional background, this just feels natural to me. I don't expect you to agree, as this is entirely a matter of taste.

Comment: fair enough, just be aware it may be a code smell to other python programmers

Answer (score 2):

```
word = word.upper()
all(x <= y for x, y in zip(word, word[1:]))
```

Comment: +1 that's clever. Although, doesn't it have to be `len(word)-2` ?

Comment: "<=" instead of "<", assuming double letters count as being in alphabetical order.

Comment: `len(word) - 1` is correct, but you should use `range` instead of `xrange` (it's upwards compatible)

Comment: yeah good point, for python 3...
also its not len(word)-2 because range only goes up to the stop value non-inclusive so it goes up to the len(word)-2

Comment: Nice.  How about `all(x <= y for x, y in zip(word[:-1], word[1:]))`

Answer (score 2):

I have a feeling this is homework, so I'm only going to give an algorithm, not copy-paste code.

The approach I would take would be to split the text file into an array of individual words.

Then, for each word, pass it into a predicate which performs the following:

1. Converts the string to lower case
2. Splits the word into an array of characters.
3. Iterates over the array of characters, starting at the SECOND character
4. Test if character[x] >= character[x-1] . If not, return false
5. If you manage to exit the iteration loop without failing, return true.

Then just increase a counter every time the predicate returns true.

Comment: You don't have to convert a string to an array in Python -- strings are sequences already. The rest sounds correct, if un-Pythonic.