# Going through a list of words and counting the words that are in alphabetical order

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a text file with thousands of words in it. I have to count the number of words that are in alphabetical order. The following is cut out from a bunch of other code I've got:

```
Counter = 0
    for word in wordStr:
    word = word.strip()
    if len(word) > 4:
    a = 0
    b = 1
    while word[a] < word[b]:
        a += 1
        b += 1
        Counter += 1
return Counter
```

There are some obvious things wrong here and I know it, but don't know how to fix it. My reasoning is this: if the first letter of a word is < the second letter of the word, that part of the word is alphabetical. So I need to go through and perform this kind of operation on a word until I find the entire word to be alphabetical or run into a situation where letter a is > letter b.

At the moment, my code increases the Counter when word[a] < word[b]. However, I need to change this so it only increases when the entire word is alphabetical, not just the first two letters. My other problem is that I get errors because eventually the while loop tries to compare string indexes that don't exist because of the way I am incrementing a and b. I know lots need to be rewritten and I have got the logic down.. just struggling to implement it.

EDIT: I forgot I have had this problem before and someone on my other question helped me solve it. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you tell if a word is in alphabetical order in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882526/how-do-you-tell-if-a-word-is-in-alphabetical-order-in-python) and also of [How to figure out if a word in spelled in alphabetical order in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388032/how-to-figure-out-if-a-word-in-spelled-in-alphabetical-order-in-python), both asked by this same user!

Comment: just use `>` or `<` to match which word is bigger or shorter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easy way to see if a word is in alphabetical order is to sort it, then see if the sorted version is the same as the original version. Python has a function `sorted()` that can be use to sort a string; however, the result will come out as a list. So you'll need to convert the sorted version back to a string, or else convert the original string to a list (the second is a bit easier, just pass the string into `list()`), before comparing them.

You might also want to convert the string to lower case (or upper case -- doesn't matter as long as it's consistent) first because that will affect the sorting order: all capital letters come before lower case ones, so `Cat` would test as already being in alphabetical order even though it isn't. You can do this using the `.lower()` method on the string object.

Since this looks like homework I won't post working code but it should be very simple to put together from what I've given you.